How can make all packages in a monorepo share the same verison of a dependency?
I am using nx to manage a monorepo which includes 100 nodejs projects. All source code is in typescript. Each project has its own package.json file which has typescript as its dev dependency. My question is how can I force every package.json use the same typescript version? When I want to upgrade typescript version, I'd like to update one place which apply to all packages.

That honestly sounds like the kind of thing we explicitly invented (shell) scripting for. Write a script that takes one or more runtime args, and then runs npm install all those args in every subdir that has a package.json in it? (heck, you could even write that as a Node script that uses process.argv, readdir, and exec, if you want to make sure it'll run anywhere that your Node can run, rather than using something that locks devs into a specific OS)

Instead of reinventing a pm, he could use something like renovate. I think the OP is looking for a way to prevent installing another version of the package

Having all projects of a monorepo share the same version of a (dev)dependency is indeed one of the use cases for monorepo.
And the simple way to implement it is to specify that dependency at the root of the monorepo, in a "shared" package.json file, instead of within each project own package.json:
Nx > Concepts > Dependency Management > Single Version Policy

With this strategy, developers define all dependencies in the root package.json file. This enforces a single version for all dependencies across the codebase

Note that this is not specific to Nx, many other monorepo managers recommend this, as it simply relies on Node built-in module resolution strategy:

Node.js starts at the directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and attempts to load the module from that location. [...]
If it is not found there, then it moves to the parent directory, and so on, until the root of the file system is reached.

Even if that means going outside a project root folder.
You usually push this strategy further by specifying all dependencies exclusively in the root package.json, even if some of these dependencies are used only by a few projects in the monorepo. If some of them require bundling their dependencies, the monorepo management tool usually helps in curating the list:

the plugins Nx provides come with executors that use Nx's graph of dependencies to automatically populate the dependencies section of the individual package.json files in the build output


thanks so much, this was a really enlightening answer. in the java world, the same sort of "inheritance" through pom.xml files applies. I didnt know that node also worked in this manner
